# How to disable the double-tap event in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm building a custom web app and one feature that keeps getting in the way is the "double-tap-to-zoom" on the UIWebView.  I've looked on this forum and the web and I don't see an obvious way to disable this.

How can I disable or ignore double-tap-to-zoom in my app?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you tap the webview? Is is supposed to react like a browser?

Comment: It seems clear Craig wants to disable the double tap ... it depends on the framework you Craig is using.

Comment: 3pic is right, I want to disable the double tap entirely if it's possible, as the solutions provided below - while fixing the issue - zooms the page in on load.  3pic, I'm using the 8.1 framework (is that what you needed to know?)

Answer (score 5):

You simply can disable zooming with putting this code in your viewDidLoad Method:

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

There is another approach for this. Add this meta tag to the head section of your webView contents:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!  Such a simple and efficient solution to a problem I thought was going to be a headache!  The scalePageToFit did the trick.

Comment: I spoke too soon, while this did fix the problem it is now zoomed all the way in by default

Comment: Try this: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 5.0;"];`

Comment: or this: `[self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES];`

Comment: lol, I was just trying that on my own ([myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"user-scalable=0\">"];) when that didn't work I came back here to see your new comments :).  I tried both of those zoom commands and while both helped a bit, it's still zoomed in

Comment: I'm using [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 0.75;"]; and it's much better but it seems like it's a bit unpredictable in that first I have to find the exact right partial zoom and also what happens if it's on a different device (i.e, iPad vs iPhone)?

Comment: I think what I really need to do is completely disable the double tap action itself.

Comment: why do you want to disable double tap?

Comment: I don't want the zoom, but it seems that disabling scaling doesn't work for the page I'm displaying so I would think disabling double-tap gets me where I need to be.

Comment: @CraigS i edited my answer below.. did you want to try to see if it works

Answer (score 5):

Craig : yo are doing a web app... your code is HTML/Css/Js, I guess.

> Solution: use this in `<head></head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">
```

---

Advice
You would win if you learn about meta viewport option. Very useful when doing web app for mobiles. Particularly Apple ones.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't state that I did not want to edit the web pages for the solution to work but I was looking to change the app itself.

Comment: Oh ok. so you ve got the answer, nice. (gimme a +1 ;) )

Answer (score 2):

First option - You can disabled double tap and pinch to zoop by setting this.

```
_webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
_webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Second Option - You can execute the following piece of code in webViewDidFinishLoad to prevent double tap - zoom

```
NSString *js = @"var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');"
"metaTag.name = \"viewport\";"
"metaTag.content = \"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0\";"
"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I marked the first answer as the one that solved my problem but I've also incorporated your mutlipleTouchEnabled as well!

Comment: @CraigS I edited my answer to add another option to run a JS to prevent zoom.. You need not set `scalesPageToFit = NO` anymore with this change.. It should work. Let me know how it goes

Comment: The double-tap is disabled when I put this in the webViewDidFinishLoad but it's zoomed way in again

Comment: did you try removing all the other code you added to set the zoom scale and set the `scalesPageToFit` back to YES.. I tested this and is working as desired

Comment: Yes, I did, both the scalePageToFit is commented out as well as multipleTouchEnabled, so I'm now doing nothing more than that code you provided in my webViewDidFinishLoad

Answer (score 0):

A weird solution (don't ask me how it works) is to hide the status bar. With the status bar hidden, the doble tap does not zoom the webview anymore.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}
```